# Build and Upload Simultaneously in Eclipse

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, embedded, arm

**Question**

Is there a plugin (or built-in feature) for Eclipse that will allow you to **build** and **upload** a compiled program (C++ .so or Java .jar) via SSH in one click or command **without running**? I know you can use Apache Ant for this, but I am looking for an Eclipse built-in solution, so I can still use Eclipse's auto build features.

**Context**

I am building an application for an embedded ARM computer connected via SSH. My test cycle is currently to build (cross-compilation), upload, and run in three separate steps. I would like to consolidate this into two steps, build and upload, then run.

My binaries are a **.so** library (which cannot be run, therefore C++ Remote Application does not work) and a **.jar**, which Eclipse will not handle the upload by default.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a shell script with build and upload command lines, then create a build target that invokes the script. You would still need to manually invoke the build (doubleclick the build target, Build All or something); I am not sure if that fits your goal of "auto build".